# Select from a string with a binary number

Tags: python, string, binary, selection

How to use a binary to select from a tuple? (in Python)

Eg. 10101, select the first element (1) not the second (0), select the third(1), and not the fourth, select the fifth and the sixth etc.. (101011)

```
a = 101011
b = 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'
```

how to use a to select 'a', 'c', 'e','f' ?

is there a clean way to do this? preferably in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an interactive session demonstrating one approach

```
bash-3.2$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 29 2016, 14:57:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a, b = 101011, ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')

>>> a, b
(101011, ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'))

>>> list(str(a))
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1']

>>> zip(list(str(a)),b)
[('1', 'a'), ('0', 'b'), ('1', 'c'), ('0', 'd'), ('1', 'e'), ('1', 'f')]

>>> filter(lambda x:x[0]=='1', zip(list(str(a)),b))
[('1', 'a'), ('1', 'c'), ('1', 'e'), ('1', 'f')]

>>> [x[1] for x in filter(lambda x:x[0]=='1', zip(list(str(a)),b))]
['a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

we can make this a little cleaner using destructuring assignment

```
>>> [y for x,y in zip(list(str(a)),b) if x=='1']
['a', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 101011
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
result = []
temp = list(str(a))
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if temp[i] == '1':
        result.append(b[i])
print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your answer! While this code may work as-is, it helps the user asking the question more if you can also describe why your answer works, and in what way the user was likely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This will handle the general case. It extracts the bits from the int (*num*) - it does not expect a binary string conversion (e.g. 101010).

```
def bin_select(num, mylist):
    idx = 1
    out = []
    while num:
        if (num & 1 != 0):
            out.append(mylist[-idx])
        num = num >> 1
        idx += 1
    return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(bin_select(7, ["a","b","c"]))
    print(bin_select(6, ["a","b","c"]))
```